# iOS UiView layout issue

Tags: ios

My code is as follows:

```
let payBackView = UIView(frame: CGRect.sizeMake(x: 10, y: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height - 86, width: 369, height: 52))
self.view.bringSubviewToFront(payBackView)
payBackView.layer.cornerRadius = 21
payBackView.layer.masksToBounds = true
payBackView.backgroundColor = .white
self.view.addSubview(payBackView)
```

iOS simulator iPhone 12Pro is what I want, but simulator iphone11 pro Max is abnormal.I want to know why and what should I do ？[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MuyZM.jpg)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wo0DO.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You ***really*** should be taking advantage of auto-layout / constraints.

Take a look at this:

```
    let payBackView = UIView()
    payBackView.layer.cornerRadius = 21
    payBackView.layer.masksToBounds = true
    payBackView.backgroundColor = .white
    
    // we'll be using auto-layout constraints
    payBackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    
    // add payBackView to view
    self.view.addSubview(payBackView)
    
    // respect safe-area
    let g = self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
    
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        
        // we want 10-pts on each side
        payBackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 10.0),
        payBackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: -10.0),
        
        // aligned to the bottom
        payBackView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.bottomAnchor),
        
        // Height: 52-pts
        payBackView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 52.0),
        
    ])
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using a fixed width for payBackView and This is why your view on a bigger screen such as 11 pro max will be smaller. Try this:

```
let payBackView = UIView(frame: CGRect.sizeMake(x: 10, y: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height - 86, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width - 40, height: 52))
```

Answer (score 0):

UIScreen is a bad idea some iPhone has a bezel and some don't. To make sure all your views stay at the visible "zone" you have to use constraints and relate them to "Safe Area". "Safe Area" is where all kinds of iPhones with or without a bezel acts the same.
You may lose the bezel part in your design.